# Merging dataset into Dimension table with potentially duplicate PK's due to dimension history

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, modeling

I'm playing around with some snowflake ingestion from S3 using snowpipe and I've hit a slight snag with handling the edge case of multiple updates to a given dimension arriving at the same time.

**The Background**:

i have a source dumping heaps of parquet files in an S3 Bucket. Ideally we want to process these files and load them into snowflake, using snowpipe. For simplicty sake lets say the data has the below shape:

​

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | MODIFIED_ON | IS_DELETED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | doe | 2022-11-01 | False |
| 2 | jane | doe | 2022-11-01 | False |

I'm currently reading these files and their data raw into snowflake using snowpipe and COPY INTO from the S3 bucket. Storing them as a raw Variant with an INGEST_TIMESTAMP column in a table called RAW_PEOPLE.

​

| PARQUET_RAW | INGEST_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| {data:stuff} | 2022-11-01 22:50:00 |

I have a steam configured off this table, which is driving a snowflake Task every few minutes to flatten out the Variant Data into a table called STG_PEOPLE. So now i have a table with:

​

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | MODIFIED_ON | IS_DELETED | INGEST_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 2022-11-01 22:50:00 |
| 2 | jane | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 2022-11-01 22:50:00 |

​

I have also configured a stream of this table to track CDC and would like to make a merge procedure to handle move this dataset into the final table outlined below:

Finally I have a target DIM_PEOPLE table which is a type 2 SCD table with the following columns:

ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MODIFIED_ON, IS_DELETED, RECORD_CREATED_TS,  RECORD_ACTIVE_FROM_TS, RECORD_ACTIVE_TO_TS

​

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | MODIFIED_ON | IS_DELETED | RECORD_ACTIVE_FROM_TS | RECORD_ACTIVE_TO_TS | RECORD_ACTIVE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 1900-01-01 |  | Y |
| 2 | jane | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 1900-01-01 |  | Y |

​

I made up a very basic diagram to illustrate:

[high level diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYJsh.png)

​

**The Problem**:

I cannot gurantee that the source wont drop multiple updates to the same ID in the same file, or that we might have multiple files build up that contain the updates to the same ID.

So in a given ingest run i could get the below data turn up in STG_PEOPLE that i want to merge into DIM_PEOPLE:

​

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | MODIFIED_ON | IS_DELETED | INGEST_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John-joe | doe | 2022-11-02 | False | 2022-11-02 23:00 |
| 2 | jane | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 2022-11-02 23:00 |
| 1 | john-bill-joe | doe | 2022-11-03 | False | 2022-12-03 23:00 |

I dont want to discard historical changes either. But I'm struggling on how to gracefully merge this STG_PEOPLE set into the DIM_PEOPLE set in a single merge statement?

As determining record active from periods for ID = 1, my plan is to set the latest ingest timestamp to active, and set the earlier duplicate record to have an active duration of 0, ie it has the same EFFECTIVE FROM and EFFECTIVE TO

My ideal dataset might be something like the below?

​

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | MODIFIED_ON | IS_DELETED | RECORD_ACTIVE_FROM_TS | RECORD_ACTIVE_TO_TS | RECORD_ACTIVE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john-bill-joe | doe | 2022-11-03 | False | 2022-11-02 23:00 |  | Y |
| 1 | John-joe | doe | 2022-11-02 | False | 2022-11-02 23:00 | 2022-11-02 23:00 | N |
| 1 | John | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 1900-01-01 | 2022-11-02 23:00 | N |
| 2 | jane | doe | 2022-11-01 | False | 1900-01-01 |  | Y |

​

So my question is, within snowflake how would you execute a merge gracefully from a CDC stream if you capture multiple updates to the same record in the stream? Potentially i could union select both the target and source together and do some ranking in the merge, but it seems a bit heavyweight?

Thanks for taking the time to read my stream of consciousness, any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to merge this data using a ranking merge outlined below:

```
SET curr_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

MERGE INTO DIM_PEOPLE TARGET
        USING (
    SELECT
        PARQUET_RAW:id ID,
        PARQUET_RAW:first_name::STRING FIRST_NAME,
        PARQUET_RAW:last_name::STRING LAST_NAME,
        PARQUET_RAW:created_by::STRING CREATED_BY,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(PARQUET_RAW:created_on::NUMBER,3) CREATED_ON,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(PARQUET_RAW:modified_on::NUMBER,3) MODIFIED_ON,
        PARQUET_RAW:modified_by::STRING MODIFIED_BY,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PARQUET_RAW:id
    ORDER BY
        COALESCE(TO_TIMESTAMP(PARQUET_RAW:modified_on::NUMBER,3),
        TO_TIMESTAMP(PARQUET_RAW:created_on::NUMBER,3)) DESC,
        INTEGRATION_RECORD_CREATED_DT DESC) RANK,
        INTEGRATION_RECORD_CREATED_DT
    FROM
        STG_PEOPLE
    WHERE
        INTEGRATION_RECORD_CREATED_DT > 
        {INSERTED TIMESTAMP}
    ORDER BY
        PARQUET_RAW:id,
        COALESCE(TO_TIMESTAMP(PARQUET_RAW:modified_on::NUMBER,3),
        TO_TIMESTAMP(PARQUET_RAW:created_on::NUMBER,3)) DESC,
        INTEGRATION_RECORD_CREATED_DT DESC
) AS SOURCE_TABLE
ON
    SOURCE_TABLE.ID = TARGET.ID
    -- DEACTIVATE OLD RECORD
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.RECORD_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
THEN UPDATE SET
    TARGET.RECORD_ACTIVE_TO = $curr_time,
    TARGET.RECORD_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'N',
    TARGET.RECORD_MODIFIED_DT = $curr_time
    --INSERT ANY NEW RECORD FOR AN UPDATE
--insert newest version
WHEN MATCHED AND SOURCE_TABLE.RANK = 1
THEN
INSERT (ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CREATED_BY,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,RECORD_CREATED_DT,RECORD_MODIFIED_DT,RECORD_ACTIVE_FROM,RECORD_ACTIVE_TO,RECORD_ACTIVE_FLAG,RECORD_INTEGRATION_TIMESTAMP)
VALUES(
ID,
FIRST_NAME,
LAST_NAME,
CREATED_BY,
CREATED_ON,
MODIFIED_BY,
MODIFIED_ON,
$curr_time,
$curr_time,
$curr_time,
TO_TIMESTAMP('2999-01-01'),
'Y',
RECORD_INTEGRATION_TIMESTAMP 
)
--insert older versions
--WONT WORK BECAUSE THIS IS NOT PREDICATED ON MATCHED/NOT MATCHED
WHEN SOURCE_TABLE.RANK != 1
THEN
INSERT (ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CREATED_BY,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,RECORD_CREATED_DT,RECORD_MODIFIED_DT,RECORD_ACTIVE_FROM,RECORD_ACTIVE_TO,RECORD_ACTIVE_FLAG,RECORD_INTEGRATION_TIMESTAMP)
VALUES(
SOURCE_TABLE.ID,
SOURCE_TABLE.FIRST_NAME,
SOURCE_TABLE.LAST_NAME,
SOURCE_TABLE.CREATED_BY,
SOURCE_TABLE.CREATED_ON,
SOURCE_TABLE.MODIFIED_BY,
SOURCE_TABLE.MODIFIED_ON,
$curr_time,
$curr_time,
$curr_time,
$curr_time,
'N',
SOURCE_TABLE.RECORD_INTEGRATION_TIMESTAMP 
);
```

But this does not work as the case to append new records for duplicates which are lower rank does not actually meet the 'MATCHED' or 'NOT MATCHED' criteria.